# Mapping 2 columns in a single table to a column in a separate table with typeorm

Tags: node.js, database, graphql, typeorm, entity-relationship

operations table

| op ID | Operation name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cutting |
| 2 | Sewing |

job groups table

| Job group | op IN | op OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| grp1 | 1 | 2 |
| grp2 | 4 | 5 |

I have the above 2 tables , I want to map these two using typeorm

op In and op out are operation IDs.

I want to fetch for a given job group , the names and ids of the operations it has preferably in a single call (operation in and operation out)

How can I do this mapping using type orm relationships? I am trying to map 2 columns in 1 table to 1 column in a separate table.

Also I am using a graphql API, I am under the assumption if I can add the relationship properly I can fetch these information in a single graphql query.

Any assistance is appreciated.